# Execute dynamic command into all screen sessions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, display, java

I am working on setting up a minecraft server network in ubuntu server 14.04 LTS. I have several screen sessions each with their own process running in them

```
There are screens on:
    2471.LobbyServer (detached)
    2468.BungeeCordProxy (detached)
```

I need a way to type a single command (perhaps launching a bash script) that will loop through all of the screen sessions, and enter a command into each of the running processes (each of the processes accepts commands as input while running) depending on the jar file being used in the process (both processes are .jar files launched with Oracle java-7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can run:

```
screen -S panel -p 0 -X stuff "yourCommand`echo -ne '\015'`"
```

The `-p` is the window number and the `echo` part inserts a newline at the end

Comment: Is there some way to loop through and execute a different command depending on what jar file is running?

Comment: Ouch! That's a big ask. I think I might look for a different answer than stuffing text into the console in that case. At least, if you should try to have each jar type in a specific named screen session so you know in advance which command to send. If not, I think you need to look for a more sophisticated way of communicating with the jar apps.

Comment: Yep, that's why I asked it here (there are lots of smart people here). I can add code to the jar apps fairly easily, but the problem is that how could I have the code communicate with the rest of the system (the best I can think of is having a file that is read over and over by the java app, and when it sees a certian code (perhaps "stop") it just stops, I already, which seems pretty inefficient).?

Comment: You are thinking along the same lines as me. File system access is very efficient on UNIX like systems. I'd add a file-system monitor to the Java app and when the file system triggers a new file event on the watched folder, trigger a sub-routine to read and delete the file, parse the content for known commands and execute accordingly. You are really implementing a message bus in miniature. A useful bit of function. I've done similar but monitoring IMAP mail folders in the past (with PHP rather than Java).